# \sffamily with \pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm trying to create a table using `pgfplotstable`. It works almost fine, just asking myself why `\sffamily` in front of `\pgfplotstabletypeset` is not working.

Answer (score 5):

The numbers in `pgfplotstable` are typeset in math mode.  In order to influence the way they are typed you either need to load a package that changes the math fonts or use a `\mathversion` command.  By default LaTeX only defines math versinos `normal` and `bold`.  As you only need a limited number of symbols for typesetting numbers, you can set up a math version `sans serif` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\DeclareMathVersion{sansserif}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sansserif}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}

\pgfplotstableread{
level   dof error1
1   4   2.50000000e-01
2   16  6.25000000e-02
3   64  1.56250000e-02
4   256 3.90625000e-03
5   1024    9.76562500e-04
6   4096    2.44140625e-04
7   16384   6.10351562e-05
8   65536   1.52587891e-05
9   262144  3.81469727e-06
10  1048576 9.53674316e-07
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \sffamily \mathversion{sansserif} \pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

When `\mathversion{sansserif}` is in force, any `operator` font symbols are set to `cmss`, the sans serif version of computer modern.  (`lmss` would be an obviosu alternative if using latin modern fonts).  Now we can switch to sans serif for text via `\sffamily` and for math via `\mathversion{sansserif}`.  Switch back with `\normalfont` and `\mathversion{normal}`.

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplotstable` relies on LaTeX's famous math mode to typeset its numbers. This, in turn, does not work with `\sffamily`.

That said, I am always a little bit confused of what the actual answer is as I never really understood the details of math fonts. If I am not mistaken, one has to add some special `\usepackage` instruction to replace math fonts throughout the document. But I hope that I am wrong.

Perhaps you should search for the answers to the question "How can I use sans serif fonts in math mode" -- the answer is applicable here as well.